# Does anyone know how to add superscripts in the option tag of <select>

Tags: html, css, styling

Does anyone know how to add superscripts in the option tag of

```
<select name=" ">
    <option value=" ">24<sup>th</sup></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Option tags cannot have any child elements

Answer (score 12):

If your users have the appropriate fonts ([here's](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d57/fontsupport.htm) a list), you can use the Unicode superscript characters:

```html
<select name=" ">
  <option value=" ">24&#x1D57;&#x02B0;</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Just an FYI for people needing massive browser support -- many of these are not supported in IE8 and IE7, as well as android browsers https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18919

Comment: This does not require UTF-8 or another Unicode encoding. The character references work independently of character encoding. The real problem is font support (which primarily depends on fonts, not browsers).

Answer (score 2):

If you set the document encoding to UTF-8 or use unicode escapes you could use [Unicode superscripts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts) for this, e.g.:

```
<option>25ᵗʰ</option>
```

However, this may not display properly at all in some fonts or browsers and generally isn't as nice-looking as using the HTML/CSS superscript functionality.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, and for the future, I mention the possibility of using OpenType features of a font, via [`font-feature-settings`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-feature-settings?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/font-feature-settings) in CSS. Using the [`ordn` feature](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/features_ko.htm#ordn), you can specify that superscript letters be used from the font, if available. Support in browsers and fonts is still very limited, but the following works in sufficiently new browsers on sufficiently new versions of Windows (which have the “C fonts” like Calibri installed):

```css
select,
option {
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: "ordn";
  -moz-font-feature-settings: "ordn";
  font-feature-settings: "ordn";
  font-family: Calibri;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>24th</option>
</select>
```

This can only be used if *all* letters in the `option` content are to be shown as superscripts.

The approach degrades gracefully: when the technique does not work, the rendering just falls back to showing “24th” normally.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using span
[Check it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kl3Et.png)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541

Comment: as starball mentioned please put your code in the answer not the picture of that

Answer (score -1):

Because a select box anctual often an OS object rather than soemthing that is draw by the browser you are limited to what this object can do.

It is a Listbox or Combobox on Windows and these do not have the capability of drawing super scripts.

I am afraid you will have to live without being able to do it.

Answer (score -3):

You can write this way,

```
string item=HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("ml/min/1.73m&amp;#178;")
```

for more information on superscript you can see this link
http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/bylanguage/mathchart.html#super