# How to add <sup> tag with in optgroup label

Tags: html

Want to add a sup-script within optgroup label..

```
<select name="ddlSemester">
    <option selected>--Select--</option>
        <optgroup>"11<sup>th</sup>"</optgroup>
            <option>I Sem</option>
            <option>II Sem</option>
        <optgroup label="11"<sup>th</sup>>
            <option>I Sem</option>
            <option>II Sem</option>
        </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790214/does-anyone-know-how-to-add-superscripts-in-the-option-tag-of-select

Comment: Didn't found that on google... Thank's man...

Comment: I couldn't find superscript -st, -nd, -rd and -th in Unicode, which is a shame, because that would have been a nice answer. If it helps, Wikipedia claims [ordinals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_numerals#Ordinal_numbers) don't have to be superscript: *"The suffixes -th, -st, -nd and -rd are occasionally written superscript above the number itself"*