# hex code for superscript s to remove superscript

Tags: html

i want to write 1st in which st would be shown as superscript of 1.
can anybody tell me the hex code for superscript small s in html

code:

```
 <form>
Year:<select name="year">
         <option value="1">1<sup>st</sup></option>
         </script>
 </form>
```

plz provide some solution because superscript is not working.
 i want to write 1st in which st would be shown as superscript of 1.
can anybody tell me the hex code for superscript small s in html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does anyone know how to add superscripts in the option tag of <select>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790214/does-anyone-know-how-to-add-superscripts-in-the-option-tag-of-select)

Answer (score 2):

You can't have `<sup>` inside an `<option>` tag. There's very little formatting you *can* have in an `<option>` (if any). You can't do it with a Unicode character either - [there isn't a codepoint for st, th, etc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts).

Comment: so it means no solution to it?

Comment: There are code points for superscript s and superscript t. See answers to the old question that this is a duplicate for.

Comment: @Jukka So there is, although implementing it will be a bit of a pain. Not worth the time and effort IMO. There's also the issue of poor support in certain fonts/browsers